# Making sequential line(cv2) from numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I have a numpy array that consist n (x and y)  coordinate (i declared this nparray as 'line') from an image(newimg). lets take 5 coordinates as the example

```
[[ 33 101]
 [170  95]
 [151 190]
 [125 223]
 [115 207]]
```

an then i want to make a sequential line between that coordinates (point 1 to point 2, point 2 to point 3, ...., point n-1 to point n and the point n to point 1)

I trying to make the algorithm with cv2.line like this

```
for a in range(5) :
   cv2.line(newimg, line[a:], line[a+1:], (255,255,255), 1)
cv2.line(newimg, line, line[1], (255,255,255), 1)
```

and it produce SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

any idea?

Comment: can you provide minimal code to initialize the cv2 image?

Comment: img = cv2.imread("./class_image_6/298.jpg")

and the image looks like this 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flashsss/TIIA/main/image.png'

Comment: we don't have your image, what about generating a blank image of the same shape?

Comment: i edited my last reply

Comment: you seem to misunderstand how "slicing" works. **do not** say `line[a:]`. **do say** `line[a]`. that will get you closer to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems:**

There are some changes that need to be addressed:

1. To access a single value in an array use `line[i]`. `line[i:]` returns an array of points staring from index `i` till the end.
2. `cv2.line()` accepts tuples as start and end points.

**Code:**

```
# proposed line as an array
line = np.array([[ 33, 101], [170,  95], [151, 190], [125, 223], [115, 207]])

# blank image
newimg = np.zeros((300, 300, 3), np.uint8)

# iterate every point and connect a line between it and the next point
for a in range(len(line) - 1):
    newimg = cv2.line(newimg, tuple(line[a]), tuple(line[a+1]), (255,255,255), 2)
newimg = cv2.line(newimg, tuple(line[0]), tuple(line[-1]), (255,255,255), 2)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT**

Updated the code to connect a line between the first and last points in `line`

Comment: OpenCV doesn't need them to be tuples anymore. it finally learned to accept numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Solve, I edited my code to

```
for a in range(4) :
    cv2.line(newimg, tuple(line[a]), tuple(line[a+1]), (255,255,255), 1)
cv2.line(newimg, tuple(line[4], tuple(line[0]), (255,255,255), 1)
```

and image:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you figured it out. You can generalize connecting the first and last points using `cv2.line(newimg, tuple(line[0]), tuple(line[-1]), (255,255,255), 1)`